# jQuery VAT calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to calculate VAT from value in span, which works, but only if value inside span is used with dot. If i use comma, it shows NaN

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#vatCalculate").ready(function () {
    var vatTextBox = $("#vatPrice").text();
    var op = (vatTextBox * 100) / 122;
    var findVat = vatTextBox - op;
    $("#vatValue").text(findVat.toFixed(2));
});
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="vatPrice">30.33</span>
<span id="vatValue"></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csgz0qmu/

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the commas, you'll need to use replace on the string. To convert to a float so you can do the maths, you'll need parseFloat:

```
var vatTextBox = parseFloat(vatTextBox.replace(/,/g, ''))
```

You really should use hidden inputs instead as well and have it stored as a double.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csgz0qmu/1/)

Comment: No it is not, if you want the comma to be a fullstop then parseFloat(vatTextBox.replace(/,/g, '.')) instead. But in most places, the comma represents in the UK something along the lines £2,000.59 etc. You did not actually state the functionality that the comma represents.

Comment: Ah yes..i see it now. Thank you for elaborating. Works as expected. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `vatTextBox` is a `string`, not a number.

Use `parseFloat()` to parse it, and replace the `,` characters with a `.`